# Prometheus Adapter Not Able to Pull Custom Metrics from Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator, prometheus-adapter

I am trying to configure the custom metrics to trigger the HPA based on `http_server_requests_second`, however I am not able to successfully pull the data of custom metrics from prometheus adapter to prometheus. Although the custom data shows up correctly in the prometheus.

I have used the helm approach to install the prometheus operator and prometheus adapter from the prometheus community itself and used `additionalscrapeconfig` to pull the metric for my demo application.

Custom Metric Data Showing up Correctly in Prometheus

[image: Prometheus Data Screenshot]

Below is the snippet of the prometheus scrape config of my application

```yaml
- job_name: "appops-springboot-hpa-demo-app"
  metrics_path: /actuator/prometheus
  static_configs:
    - targets: ["springboot-hpa-app.default.svc.cluster.local:8080"]
```

Below are different approaches I tried to change in the `configmap` of the prometheus adapter, however I am continuously getting `404` while pulling the information in prometheus adapter when the custom metric api is invoked. I have attached the `404` log at end of this post.

Please note, when I invoke custom metric API, it does pull all other default metrics comes with the helm installation itself however only my custom metrics data is not showing which means at least the connectivity is fine between prometheus adapter to prometheus.

```bash
kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1" | jq .
```

Approach 1 : (Didnt work)

```yaml
- seriesQuery: 'http_server_requests_seconds_count{namespace !="",pod!="",uri="/requests"}'
      seriesFilters: []
      resources:
        overrides:
          namespace:
            resource: namespace
          pod:
            resource: pod
      name:
        matches: ""
        as: ""
      metricsQuery: 'sum(rate(<<.Series>>{<<.LabelMatchers>>}[1m])) by (<<.GroupBy>>)'
```

Approach 2: (Didnt work)

```yaml
custom:
    - seriesQuery: '{__name__=~"^http_server_requests_seconds_.*"}' 
      resources:
        overrides:
          kubernetes_namespace:
            resource: namespace
          kubernetes_pod_name:
            resource: pod
      name:
        matches: "^http_server_requests_seconds_count(.*)" 
        as: "http_server_requests_seconds_count_sum" 
      metricsQuery: sum ( <<.Series>> { <<.LabelMatchers>>,uri=~ "/requests.*" } ) by ( <<.GroupBy>> )
```

Approach 3: (Didnt work)

```yaml
    - seriesQuery: 'http_server_requests_seconds_count{job="appops-springboot-hpa-demo-app", method="GET", status="200", uri="/requests"}' 
      resources:
        overrides:
          kubernetes_namespace:
            resource: namespace
          kubernetes_pod_name:
            resource: pod
      name:
        matches: http_server_requests_seconds_count 
        as: "http_server_requests_seconds_count_sum" 
      metricsQuery: rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{job="appops-springboot-hpa-demo-app", method="GET", status="200", uri="/requests",<<.LabelMatchers>>}[5m])
```

Output of the custom Metrics API for the expected data:

```bash
kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/*/http_server_requests_seconds_count | jq .
```

```
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource
```

Logs from Prometheus Adapter deployment :

```
I0211 00:58:38.846373       1 httplog.go:104] "HTTP" verb="GET" URI="/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/ops-poc/pods/%2A/http_server_requests_seconds_count?labelSelector=app%3Dspringboot-custom-hpa" latency="15.099215ms" userAgent="kube-controller-manager/v1.22.13 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/a43c090/system:serviceaccount:kube-system:horizontal-pod-autoscaler" audit-ID="351e31aa-c8c9-4558-bb33-f265638ef678" srcIP="10.42.15.0:57042" resp=404
```

Comment: Just a minor comment: if your Metric in Prometheus has Labels: `exception`, `instance`, `job`, `method`, `status`, and `uri`, then that's the set of valid keys for `resources.overrides`.

Answer (score -1):

your metric doesnt have any reference to namespace or pod so you should not use

resources:
overrides:
kubernetes_namespace:
resource: namespace
kubernetes_pod_name:
resource: pod
you need to make the configuration match the metric

Discovery, which specifies how the adapter should find all Prometheus metrics for this rule.

Association, which specifies how the adapter should determine which Kubernetes resources a particular metric is associated with.

Naming, which specifies how the adapter should expose the metric in the custom metrics API.

Querying, which specifies how a request for a particular metric on one or more Kubernetes objects should be turned into a query to Prometheus.

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/prometheus-adapter/blob/master/docs/config.md